# NavigationService in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to understand Silverlight 5 now

I have two pages,
MainPage.xaml and OtherPage.xaml.

I have created a button in MainPage.xaml to navigate to OtherPage.xaml

In Silverlight for Windows Phone 7, I know it's something like this

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/OtherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

How is this done in Silverlight 5 for web application? please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not have the WP7 NavigationService, but there is the [Silverlight Navigation Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It is a little more complicated to use than the code you pasted above. Here is a link to a tutorial:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx

However, if all you are looking for is to switch from one usercontrol to another, the following technique may be enough:
http://craign.net/2008/03/11/how-to-switch-silverlight-usercontrols/

Hope it helps.